# Online Quote form - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms

I am trying to create an online form with javascript calculations for a website.

My first step was to create the form / table in excel. I then converted the table to html using an online service. I now have the generated html code, which is great, but I see that the fields are not 'editable' form the form. I have tried removing the 'sample' data within the spreadsheet before converting, but the fields are still not editable?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.tableizer-table {
    border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: <?php echo $tableFont ?>;
    font-size: 12px;
} 
.tableizer-table td {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tableizer-table th {
    background-color: #104E8B; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style><table class="tableizer-table">
<tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Date</th><th>Amount of Delegates ½ Day Conference @ R 240 pp</th><th>Amount of Delegates Full Day Conference @ R 260 pp</th><th>Menu No</th><th>Price pp for Menu       (1-7: R70, 8-10 R85, 11: R105, 12: R85)</th><th>Total persons for Meals </th><th>Amount of Single Rooms @ R 480 pp</th><th>Amount of Double Rooms @ R 720 pp</th><th>Total for the day</th></tr>
 <tr><td>4/14/2013</td><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>70</td><td>6</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>R 5,540.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4/15/2013</td><td>1</td><td>5</td><td>8</td><td>85</td><td>6</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>R 5,650.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4/16/2013</td><td>0</td><td>6</td><td>11</td><td>105</td><td>6</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>R 5,790.00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Grand Total  for the conference</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>R 16,980.00</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: they are not editable when opened in browser?

Comment: @trajce - no, none of the fields are.  Thank you for your answer. I understand the input fields now :)  How can i use input fields, but still keep the table  aligned in colums?

Comment: Check the sample below, the table contains rows `<tr>` and columns `<td>` inside (2 in this case). 1 for the property name, and 1 for the input of the value. If you want to achieve the same as I did, just repeat the row `<tr>...</tr>` as much times as you need. Keep in mind to change the `id` of each of the inputs, so they have unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand what you mean by not editable, but i guess you mean that they have static data.  If thats the case, then you need to insert `<input type="text" />` elements.

I've provided a sample [jsfiddle.net/trajce/6jAAU](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/6jAAU/).
Here is sample HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        Name:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input tyle="text" id="name"/>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Surname:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input tyle="text" id="surname"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```